# FastAPI and Postgres Error: asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidCatalogNameError: database "auth_service" does not exist

Tags: python, database, postgresql, authentication, fastapi

I am developing Authentication service using FastAPI.
While developing, there is a critical error and I can't develop anymore.
I want to create some tables after creating auth_service database but it couldn't do well..
Of course, auth_service database is available.
And I am sure that there is no error in models.

This is my env.py file for alembic.

```
import asyncio
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool
from sqlalchemy.engine import Connection
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine

from alembic import context

from src.db.url import get_sqlalchemy_url
from src.db.base_class import Base

from src.models import *  # necessarily to import something from file where your models are stored

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

target_metadata = Base.metadata

target_metadata.naming_convention = {
   "ix": "ix_%(column_0_label)s",
   "uq": "uq_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s",
   "ck": "ck_%(table_name)s_%(constraint_name)s",
   "fk": "fk_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)"
         "s_%(referred_table_name)s",
   "pk": "pk_%(table_name)s"
}

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = get_sqlalchemy_url()
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def do_run_migrations(connection: Connection) -> None:
    context.configure(connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


async def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    configuration = config.get_section(config.config_ini_section)
    configuration["sqlalchemy.url"] = get_sqlalchemy_url()

    connectable = AsyncEngine(
        engine_from_config(
            configuration,
            prefix="sqlalchemy.",
            poolclass=pool.NullPool,
            future=True,
        )
    )

    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(do_run_migrations)

    await connectable.dispose()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    asyncio.run(run_migrations_online())
```

I run with this command : alembic revision --autogenerate -m "new migration"
But there is an error like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\Scripts\alembic.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 590, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 584, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\alembic\config.py", line 561, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 229, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 569, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 94, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 110, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)  # type: ignore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "alembic\env.py", line 100, in <module>
    asyncio.run(run_migrations_online())
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "alembic\env.py", line 91, in run_migrations_online
    async with connectable.connect() as connection:
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\base.py", line 60, in __aenter__
    return await self.start(is_ctxmanager=True)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\asyncio\engine.py", line 157, in start
    await (greenlet_spawn(self.sync_engine.connect))
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 126, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\future\engine.py", line 406, in connect
    return super(Engine, self).connect()
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3315, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 320, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 884, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 486, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 266, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 381, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 673, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 598, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\asyncpg.py", line 780, in connect
    await_only(self.asyncpg.connect(*arg, **kw)),
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 68, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_concurrency_py3k.py", line 121, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connection.py", line 2092, in connect
    return await connect_utils._connect(
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 881, in _connect
    return await _connect_addr(
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 773, in _connect_addr
    return await __connect_addr(params, timeout, True, *args)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\connect_utils.py", line 831, in __connect_addr
    await compat.wait_for(connected, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\.virtualenvs\pythonProject\lib\site-packages\asyncpg\compat.py", line 56, in wait_for
    return await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Darkness\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 479, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
asyncpg.exceptions.InvalidCatalogNameError: database "auth_service" does not exist
```

Comment: Did you try to run it once by explicitly mentioning the config file. Eg: `alembic -c <config.ini> revision --autogenerate -m "<the message>"`?